# Ubuntu 20.04: Not opening, while booting shows this error message:

Tags: boot, 20.04, grub2, bios, error-handling

[error][1]

I get this error while I try to boot my notebook, the software currently installed is ubuntu 20.04.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp6Dp.jpg